# Controlling youbot's arm. brics_actuator/JointPositions

Tags: ros, joint-state-publisher, youbot, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to integrate leap motion sensor with youBot. I wrote a test publisher to move the joints. However, when I run the python script, I am getting this error:

`youbot@youbot-desktop:~$ rosrun youbot_leap leap_armcontrol.py  Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/youbot/catkin_ws/src/youbotleap/scripts/leap_armcontrol.py", line 96, in <module> sender() File "/home/youbot/catkin_ws/src/youbotleap/scripts/leap_armcontrol.py", line 25, in sender msg.positions.joint_uri = "arm_joint_1" AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'joint_uri'`

While through the terminal, it runs fine on the bot:
`youbot@youbot-desktop:~/catkin_ws$ rostopic pub -1 /arm_1/arm_controller/position_command brics_actuator/JointPositions '{positions:[{joint_uri: arm_joint_5, unit: rad, value: 1}]}' publishing and latching message for 3.0 seconds`

The message:

`youbot@youbot-desktop:~$ rosmsg show brics_actuator/JointPositions  brics_actuator/Poison poisonStamp string originator string description float32 qos brics_actuator/JointValue[] positions time timeStamp string joint_uri string unit float64 value`

Here's the code:

```
import rospy
from brics_actuator.msg import JointPositions
pub_youbotleap_arm = rospy.Publisher('arm_1/arm_controller/position_command', JointPositions)
rospy.init_node('armcontrol')

rate = rospy.Rate(20)

msg = JointPositions()

msg.positions.joint_uri = "arm_joint_1"
msg.positions.unit = "rad"
msg.positions.value = 2

pub_youbotleap_arm.publish(msg)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sender()
    rospy.spin()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173395/controlling-youbot%27s-arm.-brics_actuator/jointpositions/) by [ratneshmadaan](https://answers.ros.org/users/12636/ratneshmadaan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2014-06-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`msg.positions` is a list of `brics_actuator.msg.JointValue` messages. Thus, you should fill your message accordingly:

```
from brics_actuator.msg import JointValue

msg.positions = [brics_actuator.msg.JointValue()]
msg.positions[0].joint_uri = "arm_joint_1"
msg.positions[0].unit = "rad"
msg.positions[0].value = 2
```

---

Originally posted by [jsanch2s](https://answers.ros.org/users/25919/jsanch2s/) with karma: 136 on 2016-11-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1